# Por qué no itera mi bucle for?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Pensaba que siempre se iteraba sobre el argumento de la función donde estaba el bucle for, pero en este caso no es así. Evidentemente estoy equivocado.

Alguien me podría explicar por favor por qué no itera en este caso, y de paso decirme sobre qué exactamente itera el bucle for en general?? Gracias de ante mano

```
function breakStatement(numero) {
  //Iterar en un bucle aumentando en 2 el numero recibido hasta un límite de 10 veces.
  //Guardar cada nuevo valor en un array. 
// Tu código:
  var arrayNuevo = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    arrayNuevo = numero + 2
  }
return arrayNuevo;
}
console.log(breakStatement(5)) // 7
```

Comment: ¿Es Javascript? El script está funcionando bien, lo que está pasando es que estás haciendo 10 veces la suma: `5 + 2` y el resultado lo asignas a la variable `arrayNuevo`, sobreescribiendola cada vez.

Comment: Si pones un `console.log(i);` dentro del bucle verás que sí itera. El problema ya te lo dijo @aeportugal. Te aconsejo que aprendas a depurar el código, te habrías ahorrado todas las horas/días que lleves rompiéndote el coco con esto + el tiempo dedicado a abrir esta pregunta sin ningún tipo de depuración previa. **Depurar** debería ser una palabra sagrada en el mundo de la programación, pero es una práctica muy ignorada, lamentablemente.

Comment: Muchas gracias muchachos. Estoy aprendiendo y ni sabía qué es depurar código. Lo voy a aprender

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que iterar el arreglo dentro del bucle, tu código sería así:

```js
function breakStatement(numero) {
  var arrayNuevo = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    arrayNuevo[i] = numero + (i * 2);
  }
  return arrayNuevo;
}

console.log(breakStatement(5));
```